# How to generate and animate a hexagonal sine wave in javascript after drawing a hexagon in HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, html5-canvas, trigonometry

After having tried sine and cosine wave animations, I am facing issues while animating a hexagonal wave with rotating radius. I am unable to get the diagonal wave lines to be straight in the wave. They come out slightly curled.

```js
var hexStep = 0;
var hexID;

function drawAxes(context) {
  var width = context.canvas.width;
  var height = context.canvas.height;
  context.beginPath();
  context.strokeStyle = "rgb(128,128,128)";
  context.lineWidth = 1;
  // X-axis
  context.moveTo(0, height / 2);
  context.lineTo(width, height / 2);
  // Sine Wave starting wall
  context.moveTo(width / 4, 0);
  context.lineTo(width / 4, height);
  // Sine Wave Y-axis
  context.moveTo((2.5 * width) / 4, 0);
  context.lineTo((2.5 * width) / 4, height);
  // Shape Y-axis
  context.moveTo(width / 8, 0);
  context.lineTo(width / 8, height);
  context.stroke();
}

// Hexagon
function drawHexagon(context, x, y, r, side) {
  var width = context.canvas.width;
  var height = context.canvas.height;
  var angle = (2 * Math.PI) / side;
  context.beginPath();
  context.strokeStyle = "midnightblue";
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  context.moveTo(x + r, y);
  var hx = 0;
  var hy = 0;  
  for (var i = 1; i <= side; i++) {
    hx = x + r * Math.cos(angle * i);
    hy = y + r * Math.sin(angle * i);
    context.lineTo(hx, hy);
  }
  context.stroke();
}

function getHexagonalWave(context, x, y, r, side, step, freq) {
  var width = context.canvas.width;
  var height = context.canvas.height;
  var angle = (2 * Math.PI) / side;
  var inr = r * Math.sqrt(0.75);
  context.beginPath();
  context.strokeStyle = "midnightblue";
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  context.moveTo(x, y);
  var sf = step / freq;
  var hr = inr / Math.cos(((sf + angle / 2) % angle) - angle / 2);
  var hx = x + hr * Math.sin(sf);
  var hy = y - hr * Math.cos(sf);
  context.lineTo(hx, hy);
  var wx = width / 4;
  context.moveTo(hx, hy);
  context.lineTo(wx, hy);  
  context.moveTo(wx, hy);
  var hvr = 0;  
  var wvx = 0;
  var wvy = 0;
  var id = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    hvr = inr / Math.cos((((i + step) / freq + angle / 2) % angle) - angle / 2);
    wvy = y - hvr * Math.cos((i + step) / freq);
    wvx = wx + hvr * Math.sin((i + step) / freq);
    context.lineTo(wx + i, wvy);
  }
  context.stroke();
}
function doGenerateHexagonalWave() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas3");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var width = canvas.width;
  var height = canvas.height;
  var x = width / 8;
  var y = height / 2;
  var r = (1.5 * height) / 4;
  var side = 6;
  var freq = 60;
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height); // Check
  drawAxes(context);
  drawHexagon(context, x, y, r, side);  
  getHexagonalWave(context, x, y, r, side, hexStep, freq);
  hexStep++;  
  hexID = window.requestAnimationFrame(doGenerateHexagonalWave);
}

function doStopHexagonalWave() {
  window.cancelAnimationFrame(hexID);
}

function doClearHexagonalWave() {
  window.cancelAnimationFrame(hexID);
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas3");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var width = canvas.width;
  var height = canvas.height;
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);  
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color:darkgray;
  margin-left: 10px;  
}
h1 {
  margin: 5px;
}
hr {
  border: 1px solid;
}
canvas {
  margin: 5px;
  margin-bottom: -8px;
  background-color:lightgrey;
  /*
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;  
  */
}
p {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hexagonal Wave</h1>
<hr>
<div>
  </p>
  <canvas id="canvas3" width="800" height="200">
  </canvas>
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="Generate" onclick="doGenerateHexagonalWave()"/>
    <input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="doStopHexagonalWave()" />
    <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="doClearHexagonalWave()" />
  </p>
</div>
```

How do I get the angles to form straight edges between vertices in the wave by using the variable 'wvx' in the for loop ? Can't seem to figure it out!

Comment: Could you please clarify what would be the "right" behavior and what's wrong with the current one?

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you for your reply. I can't upload an image yet, as I just started here. The best I can do for a description right now is - in the oscillating wave, the current code fails to generate straight lines between vertices. dropbox.com/s/mdzngk461oxzdww/HW.png?dl=0

Comment: @Kaiido Have just added the snippet. I will be grateful for your help !

Comment: The animation looks OK to me. Can you clarify the issue?

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks for the reply. My problem is, since the angle incremented by variable 'hexStep' is hexStep++, shouldn't the resulting waveform have straight edges between the uphill and downhill edges ?. Right now, they have slightly curled edges. I can't seem to figure out how to increment the start position of the wave by the exact distance that the rotating hexagon radius covers in each animation frame. The variable 'wvx' in the for loop does calculate the x-coordinate of the rotating radius with center at 'wx'. But I just can't seem to translate it to the correct waveform.

Comment: Oh yeah, I see the curve in the waveform when I look closely.

Comment: @ggorlen thus have used 'wx +i' as x-axis increment in the for loop. Couldn't get 'wvx' to work as the increment.

Comment: @ggorlen This cleared a bit of my confusion https://1ucasvb.tumblr.com/post/42881722643/the-familiar-trigonometric-functions-can-be